# How to increment a list of values with a button

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, database

I am trying to manage a list of students in an excel database. I am trying to create a button that will increment the semester column by 1 when clicked. I have tried using an active-x button and a spinner but have not achieved my goal. My issue has been changing an entire column (or selected range) and have the selected cells increment by 1. This will be manipulating hundreds of rows.

Here is example data:

Before button press: 2, 4, 1, 6, 7...

After button press: 3, 5, 2, 7, 8...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for numeric values in the range **A2** through **A78**.  Place this code in a standard module:

```
Sub Incrementer()
    Dim rr As Range
    Set rr = Range("A2:A78")
    For Each r In rr
        r.Value = r.Value + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Place a button *(or other Shape)* on the sheet containing the data and assign the macro to the button.